# jQuery slick carousel element doesn´t appear

Tags: jquery, plugins, carousel, slick.js

for some reason the slick carousel is not working i not sure if the is a problem with the script or the css but for some reason the element on the carousel doesnt appear.

**script.js**

```
  /* Projects carousel */
  $('.project-carousel').slick({
    dots: false,
    infinite: true,
    speed: 300,
    slidesToShow: 1,
    centerMode: true,
    variableWidth: true
  });
```

**index.html**

```
<div class="row mt-5 ml-1">
  <div class="col-xs-12">
    <div class="project-carousel">
      <div class="projectos"></div>
      <div class="projectos"></div>
      <div class="projectos"></div>
      <div class="projectos"></div>
      <div class="projectos"></div>
      <div class="projectos"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**style.sass**

```
.project-carousel
  width: 100%
  height: 180px

.projectos
  width: 150px
  height: 150px
  background: rgb(255, 104, 0)
  margin: 0 10px
```

This is how it show on the webpage, for some reason the element are no appearing.

[image]

The element are there in the html bur for some reason slick is doesnt show then.

[image]

Comment: have you used `(function ($) { }`  ?

Comment: no i´m using `$(document).ready(function() { } );`

Comment: `$(document).ready` is deprecated can you try with `(function ($) { }` ?

Comment: i have a nother slider before and is working but only with the `fade` effect if i try to use `slide`  this happen i have no idea why

Comment: ok using the `(function ($) { }` happen the same

Comment: does it work in the pc ? (not in the mobile browser)

Comment: when i change to dekstop screen the elements appear but when i try to slide left or right the elements are gone and some time doesnt appear at all.

Comment: can you refresh when it's in the mobile layout ?

Comment: yes i can refresh

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167735/discussion-between-supun-fiction-praneeth-and-miguel-angel-frias).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i found the solution for this problem, i have to downgrade the version of slick, i changed for the 1.6.0 and is working just perfect, for some reason there is problem with the last version of slick.